# How do I use a template to create different constructors in C++?

Tags: c++, oop, templates, if-statement, constructor

A brief conceptual example of what I'm asking:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<string>


// Example tempate class scenario
template<int N>
class Example
{
    switch (N)
    {
    case 0:
        Example() { std::cout << "Interesting..." << std::endl; }
        break;

    case 1:
        Example () { std::cout << "Wow, didn't expect that!" << std::end; }
        break;

    case 2:
        Example() { std::cout << "Hmm..." << std::endl; }
        break;

    default:
        Example() { std::cout << "Not a valid value for N!" << std::endl; }
        break;
    }
}

// Very basic main to call constructors
int main()
{
    Example<0> a;
    Example<1> b;
    Example<2> c;
    Example<3> d;

    return 0;
}
```

If this method does work perfectly fine, then I have some more questions:

1. How would you do this with if statements instead of switches (for, e.g., strings instead of ints)?
2. If this template class was in another file than `main()`, how would you define the header file versus the cpp file for each constructor?
3. Is there a better way to go about this?
4. How would you pass parameters into constructors if, e.g., each constructor in each case took different parameters?

Comment: First of all, what is the *real* problem you need to solve? Why do you need something like this? Secondly, I suggest you look into *specialization*.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am creating a basic console game to get more familiar with C++. I would like to be able to pass a ```weaponType``` argument to a template (as an int most likely) and initialize variables in the constructor of a specific ```weapon``` object based on the template parameter's value.

Comment: Let template parameters for types and pass values as constructor parameters.

Comment: Different weapon-types sounds more like you would need inheritance. For example you could have a top-level "game object", inheriting from that you have "item", from that you have "weapon", and from that you have e.g. "gun" and "knife" etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If this method does work perfectly fine,

Your method doesn't work because expression statements cannot be in class scope.

> How do I use a template to create different constructors in C++?

This is what template specialisations are for:

```
template<int N>
class Example
{
    Example() {/*...*/} // default implementation
};

template<>
class Example<0>
{
    Example() {/*...*/} // implementation for 0
};

template<>
class Example<1>
{
    Example() {/*...*/} // implementation for 1
};
```

> How would you do this with if statements instead of switches (for, e.g., strings instead of ints)?

Strings cannot be template arguments.

> How would you pass parameters into constructors if, e.g., each constructor in each case took different parameters?

By passing the correct arguments according to the class that you're initialising.

Comment: Thank you much. And, in concerns to my second question about how to set up the header and cpp files, would you mind helping me out with that?

Comment: @DrakeJohnson Template specialisations are like regular functions. Either define them inline or declare in header and define in a source file.

Comment: I seem to be getting an error in my cpp file: ```Example<0>::Example() is not an entity that can be explicitly specialized```